# how to get next new number when you create a process in an array without using collections in Java

Tags: java

This is class of patient

```
public class Patient {

     private String name;
     private String sex;


     public Patient(String name, String sex) {
           this.name = name;
           this.sex = sex;
     }

     public String getName() {
           return name;
     }

     public String getSex() {
           return sex;
     }
}
```

This is class of process

```
public class Process {

     private String numberProcess;
     private Patient patient;

     public Process(String numberProcess, Patient patient) {
            this.numberProcess = numberProcess;
            this.patient = patient;
     }

     public String getNumberProcess() {
            return this.numberProcess ;
     }

}
```

This is class of Clinic

```
public class Clinic{

    private Patient patient[];
    private Process process[];
```

Method that takes as parameters the name and sex of a patient, checks for, creates and returns the process instance. in the case of successful creation of a new process or null in case of failure.->DOUBT HERE

```
public Process createNewProcess (String namePatient,String sexPatient) {
       if (this.process == null) {
            this.process = new Process[1];
       } else {
            this.process = Arrays.copyOf (this.process, this.process.length + 1);
       }
       for(int i = 0; i <this.patient.length; i ++) {
            if ((namePatient.equals(this.patient[i].getName()))
                  && (sexPatient.equals(this.patient[i].getSex()))) {
       return this.process[this.process.length-1] = new Process (getNewNumberProcess(), this.patient[i]);
             }
         }
         return null;
     }
```

Method that returns the next file number to be allocated -> return Number of new process -> DOUBT IS HERE in this method **getNewNumberProcess()**

```
public String getNewNumberProcess() {

        int i = 0;

         return String.valueOf(i+1);
     }
```

in main when I test:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

```
My question is 
is like an accountant but each time a process is created, then returns the new next number, that is, each time it is created, more is incremented one unit on.
example:
to create 3 processes, we obtain the three consecutive numbers, as defined here
    process number = 0001 
    process number = 0002 
    process number = 0003
    when a new process is created, the next number will be 
    process number= 0004
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Have you considered using the debugger to tell you which line is breaking?

Comment: My question is 
is like an accountant but each time a process is created, then returns the new next number, that is, each time it is created, more is incremented one unit on.
example:
to create 1 process, we obtain the first number, as defined here
    process number = 0001 
    when a new process is created, the next number will be 
    process number= 0002

Comment: You fixed your method signature, but you have `if (this.process == null) {`. Nowhere is a variable named `process` created.

Comment: the process is array with indefined size                         private Patient patient[];
private Process Process[];                                          but I used the Arrays.copyOf();

Comment: thanks for the identification of errors, and has been corrected

Comment: No worries. Not sure if those changes would fix your program, but they definitely will fix errors that will pop up later on.

Comment: the problem is not Process or process, the problem is when I made,  return this.process[this.process.length-1] = new Process (getNewNumberProcess(), this.patient[i]); , the problem is in method getNewNumberProcess()

Comment: @Drew Kennedy the prof said: consider an initial size. Usually just want to add 1 more element and sufficient that the new dimension is the old + 1. That's right but uses the Arrays.copyOf (...);

Comment: I need to they help me to resolve and understand this doubt, NOT TO GAVE ME A DOWN VOTE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, to get a new process number each time, you can use a static field.

So you add another field to your `Process` class, which is not an instance variable but a `static` field:

```
private static int nextProcessNumber = 1;
```

And then, replace your constructor. You don't need to pass it the value from the outside:

```
public Process(Patient patient) {
       this.numberProcess = nextProcessNumber++;
       this.patient = patient;
}
```

When you create a new process, you just need to pass it the patient:

```
this.process[this.process.length-1] = new Process( this.patient[i] );
```

A static variable belongs to the whole class, not to a particular instance, so the updated value is available when you create a new instance.

In real life, you'd probably want to save the value when the application finishes, and initialize it back from the saved value when it is operated again. You'd also want to protect it against concurrent modifications. But this looks like a homework assignment, so usually those things are left out.

---

If you want to control the process numbers from the `Clinic` class, you can defne the `nextProcessNumber` variable as a field in that class.

If you have more than one clinic, and each clinic has its own account 1, account 2 etc, then this should be an instance variable (not static). If there is more then one clinic, but accounts in one clinic are not allowed to have the same numbers as accounts in another clinic, it should be a static field. And if there is only one clinic, it doesn't really matter if it's static or not.

So just add another field to your `Clinic` class (together with `patient` and `process`):

```
private int nextProcessNumber = 1;
```

And your method should be:

```
public String getNewNumberProcess() {

    return String.valueOf( nextProcessNumber++ );
}
```

Comment: thank you, but I can´t use this logic because the constructor of the process is public Process(String number, Patient patient), the prof said that we need to made with this method public String getNewNumberProcess() {}

Comment: I will try, this last part, its looks interesting